# Ionic 2/Angular 4 - events does not fire in model/popover with Google Maps in background

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My app is a simple Google Map like below. When I click on marker, my custom popover appears. I have some buttons on it but when I click on them nothing happens. Events are not fired but when I click on part which is over menu everything works. In some way, maps capture my gestures instead of popover.

map.ts framgment

```
map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: Marker) => {
       marker.showInfoWindow();

       marker.on('click').subscribe(event => {                            
           let popover = this.modalCtrl.create(UserDetails, { uid: user.uid });
           popover.present()

       })
});
```

popover template:

```
<ion-content *ngIf="user">
    <ion-card>        
        <ion-card-content>
<button color="light" ion-button block (click)="close()" style="height: 300px">
                    Close                 
                </button>  
        </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to increase the popover's z-index ?

Comment: @SonHuyTRAN I tried to set it on <ion-content style="z-index: 9999" but it did not help

Comment: In this case I think you can try the InfoWindow of the Google Map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=fr

Comment: If you are using the native google maps you need to use the plugin V2 https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/whats-new-v2/README.md or add code map.setClickable(false) when open popover and map.setClickable(true) when close popover